# What are all the gadgets you can make with Slime Science?

Tags: slime-rancher

With the introduction of Slime Science, most of the blueprints used to craft gadgets seem to come from treasure pods hidden all over the Far, Far Range, and as such you never quite know when you've found them all. What are all the gadgets you can craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my goal was to know when to stop looking for treasures in a given area, the map feature introduced in 1.0.1 does exactly that. After activating a Map Module, the total and obtained amount of Slime Keys and Treasure Pods in an area is shown on the map screen.